# How to do Performance Testing of Android SDK using JMeter?

Tags: android, jmeter, sdk

There is an Ezviz SDK which is available and open source: https://open.ys7.com/doc/en/4.x/android-sdk-en.html

This SDK has been integrated inside Android APP. The link that I have shared has all the steps to integrate and call the SDK functions using Android Studio. Some of the functions are listed below:

```
    /** * Replace the APP_KEY as the one you applied.  */
    EZGlobalSDK.initLib(this, APP_KEY);

    EZGlobalSDK.getInstance().setAccessToken(String accessToken);

    EZGlobalSDK.getInstance().logout();
```

How can I create the scripts using JMeter which can call this SDK Functions? I want to do the Performance Testing of this SDK with Android App?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "create the scripts using JMeter which can call this SDK Functions", depending on what you're trying to achieve you can:

1. If you need to measure client-side performance - use [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)
2. If you need to simulate hundreds/thousands of mobile applications with integrated SDK i.e. getting devices list, video files from the cloud storage, etc. you can either record the actions in the Android application with the integrated SDK or use [PC SDK](https://open.ys7.com/doc/en/pcdoc/pc-sdk-en.html) and its demo application, whatever is easiest to you. For Android you need to set the application to use JMeter's certificate like it's described in [Network security configuration](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config) article, for the desktop application you also need to import the certificate into the [Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificate Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/trusted-root-certification-authorities-certificate-store) and maybe to add a [virtual loopback adapter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/install-microsoft-loopback-adapter), see [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter) article for more information.